# ##[error]ResourceNotFound: The Resource 'Microsoft.Web/sites/xx' under resource group 'yy' was not found in deploying ARM template

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-rm-template

I am getting resource not found in resource group error while deploying arm template.Could someone help
please .Below is the sample template used:

```
{
      "name": "[variables('AppName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
      "kind": "app",
      "location": "xx",
      "identity": {
        "type": "SystemAssigned"
      },
      "properties": {
        "httpsOnly": true,
        "clientAffinityEnabled": false,
        "serverFarmId": "xx"
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "name": "appsettings",
          "type": "config",
          "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
          "properties": {
       xx:xx
          },
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('AppName'))]",
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets', variables('keyVaultName'),'xx')]",
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets', variables('keyVaultName'),'xx')]",
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets', variables('keyVaultName'),'xx')]"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
   {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
      "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
      "name": "[concat(variables('AppName'), '/web')]",
      "location": "xx",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('AppName'))]"
      ],
}
```

Let me know is this the right way to do

Comment: Is the resource `"[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets', variables('keyVaultName'),'xx')]",` defined in your ARM template? `resourceId` only works on resources defined in the template.

Comment: Tried run the failed deployment again and got it working.It was the first time creating a resource in that rg.Thank you all for the replies

Comment: Hi JSNS, great to hear this. Always better when you fix it yourself. If my reply helped and gave a right direction for troubleshooting. Appreciate for  *marking it as an answer*. Or you could move your above comment as a reply and mark it.  Which will also help others in the community.

Answer (score 0):

its hard to tell without having the exact template and all the variables\parameters, but generally it means one of the following:

1. wrong name used for the resources that depend on the webapp somewhere
2. wrong location used for the resources that depend on the webapp somewhere
3. dependsOn isn't setup properly and it doesnt wait for the webapp and attempts to create a resource in parallel with the web app

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever use the same ARM template to deploy succeed?
Also kindly check if you could directly use script to deploy locally successful without using Azure DevOps.  This will help to narrow down the issue.

> ##[error]ResourceNotFound: The Resource 'Microsoft.Web/sites/xx' under resource group 'yy' was not found in deploying ARM template

This error indicate Resource Manager needs to retrieve the properties for a resource, but can't find the resource in your subscriptions.

You could give a try with below solution:

- Solution 1 - check resource properties
- Solution 2 - set dependencies
- Solution 3 - get external resource
- Solution 4 - get managed identity from resource
- Solution 5 - check functions

More details please take a look at our official doc here-- **[Resolve resource not found errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/error-not-found)**